# Word to say "turn it into money"

Tags: single-word-requests

Like `materialise` is to turn something into real. Is there a word to mean *turn something into money*?

e.g. *Please don't give me any medal, I would rather want you to [the word] it*.

Bet there is no `moneilise`?

Answer (score 4):

Consider *monetize* (also spelt *monetise*). You can also *sell* something, but the semantic range of *sell* is somewhat wider than simply turning something into money.

> **monetize** *verb*
>   1 Convert into or express in the form of currency.
>   ‘Hamilton had monetized the entire federal and state war debts’
>   - ODO[enter link description here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/monetize)

A web search for "monetize website" produces many relevant examples. As most of these are overtly advertising, I'll leave the searches to the reader as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you. In my country I can use the spelling `monetise`.

Comment: @user1589188 Yes, it's listed as an alternative spelling in the dictionary link; I've edited my answer to note the variant. I normally use BrE spelling, but in this case the 'z' spelling seemed more appropriate. This might have something to do with verbing the noun (an Americanism?), but I haven't checked the etymology of the word, so might be way off base here. :)